# How to use updateOrCreate proprely

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Here is my code :

```
$user = \App\User::where('id', $uid)->firstOrFail();

$user->token()->updateOrCreate(['user_id' => $uid, 'type' => $type], [
        'auth'      => $auth_token, 
        'refresh'   => $refresh_token,
        'type'      => $type
]);
```

I've got two models `User` and `Token` with an 'one to one' relationship.

On the first line, I try to catch a User into the database, then I update my model with the `updateOrCreate()` method.

However, as you can read it, I must use a selector `'user_id' => $uid` before to successfully update my model. I think Eloquent should be able to manage it in a different way without making two requests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the `user_id` => $uid on that query.  It's injected based on the relationship already.  You can rewrite that to:

```
    $token = \App\User::where('id', $uid)->firstOrFail()->token()->updateOrCreate(['type' => $type], [
            'auth'      => $auth_token, 
            'refresh'   => $refresh_token,
            'type'      => $type
    ]);
```